# What is $\theta_{GMT}$?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

What is $\theta_{GMT}$?, and how do you convert this into time and angle?

I found this article, but I don't think it's exactly what I'm looking for.
http://www.cs4fn.org/mobile/owntimezone.php

Comment: Can you provide a link to or an example of where specifically $\theta_{GMT}$ is used? Your current link certainly talks about GMT, but there's no sign of a $\theta$ nor a "theta" there.

Comment: Maybe it's just a fancy way of describing longitude? Greenwich is at 0°...

Answer (score 3):

$\theta$ is often used as the symbol for sidereal time e.g. in this [Sidereal Time](https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/Sidereal_Time) article on Navipedia. The subscript $_{GMT}$ is probably referring to Greenwich Mean Sidereal Time, albeit incompletely, at the Greenwich meridian rather than a sidereal time at a local meridian. As explained in the comprehensive [USNO Circular 179](https://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astronomical-applications/publications/Circular_179.pdf/at_download/file) ("The IAU Resolutions on Astronomical Reference Systems, Time Scales, and Earth Rotation Models") in Section 2.3, Sidereal Time is now replaced by *Earth Rotation Angle (ERA)* which also uses $\theta$ (but no subscripts are necessary now with ERA):

> Universal Time (UT) is also widely used in astronomy, and now almost always refers to the specific time scale UT1. Historically, Universal Time (formerly, Greenwich Mean Time) has been obtained from Greenwich sidereal time using a standard expression. In 2000, the IAU redefined UT1 to be a linear function of the Earth Rotation Angle,θ,

Comment: Interesting, we used to call that the 'Greenwich Hour Angle'.

Comment: You can. As the Navipedia article says: `Greenwich "Apparent" Sidereal Time (GAST): is the hour angle of "true" Aries point, from Greenwich meridian.   Greenwich Mean Sidereal Time (GMST): the same that GAST with the mean equinox.`. It's much better to think in terms of angle of where the Earth is rotated and orientated to in space, rather than a "time". Which is why ERA is a simple linear function of UT1 without any messy complications from the [equation of the equinoxes](http://star-www.rl.ac.uk/docs/sun67.htx/sun67ss87.html#Q1-91-536) and cross-coupling between the precession and nutation